# PHP page to constantly look for GET requests

Tags: php, twilio

I need to configure TWILIO SMS account to forward the received SMS to some PHP URL. So,
now if I have that PHP URL already opened in my web browser, and if some message is being forwarded to this URL from TWILIO with GET request, how can I show the received data in that already opened PHP Web URL?

Ex : If I give this URL `http://www.somephp.com/index.php` in TWILIO dashboard to forward the incoming SMS with GET request.

And I open that in my web browser already to see if there is any SMS from TWILIO. How can I constantly check if any new SMS forwarded from TWILIO?

Can I use any TIMER to check GET requests ? Or Am I totally in wrong way? I cannot find any solution around when I google. Please forgive me if it seems to be a silly question. I would be very grateful if you could guide me in this issue. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For easy you can use the jQuery library, then poll regularly for new data using a backend php script.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use some JavaScript (jQuery might be easier) to run a `setInterval` function every X seconds. Anther option is you could use a meta-refresh that would simply reload the page every X seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that way its possible to achieve what you want.

What you can do is -
set http://www.somephp.com/index.php as sms reply in you dashboard.
In index.php save any new request into a database with sender details and message content and time it was received.

Now write a new script say http://www.somephp.com/updateMessages.php
In this page use jquery or javascript to make AJAX request to a script which will connect to database and check if there are any new messages. If there is, display that message and start checking for a message received after this message.

This way if you will open http://www.somephp.com/updateMessages.php you will get all new messages here.